# How to hide partition from pantheon files?

Tags: pantheon-files, system, mount

In ubuntu i could hide a partition by going into the disks application, but in pantheon i cant find tha app, so how would i go about hiding an ntfs partition in pantheon files? ubuntu writes something in /etc/fstab file but i can't remember what it is, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:(tried)

You can use GParted tool in elementary to achieve what you want.
This is not provided by default. To install it type this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Steps to make ntfs partitions hidden:

1. Open gparted from slingshot menu
2. Right-Click on desired ntfs partitions
3. Goto Manage Flags
4. Check hidden flag
5. Log in and out or Restart

Remember to unmount the partition first.

Method 2:

Whichever filesystem you mount gets mounted to /media. In-order to hide it from pantheon files and nautilus, you need to mount it anywhere else than /media, optimal choice would be to mount it under /mnt.

Following is the link which describes how to do it in nautilus, it should be similar for pantheon files as elementary is a derivative of Ubuntu.(didn't try this for myself)

Link: [hide ntfs partition in ubuntu nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu) (check the second and third answer, first answer uses disk utility in ubuntu)

Comment: Strange. Files 0.3.1 ignores this flag on one partition (hidden), but not on another (boot, hidden, esp).

Answer (score 5):

Since you are already familiar with *Disks* and elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, why not use this application again?
Just open *Software Center*, search for *Disks* and install it.

[image: Software Center]

- start *Disks*
- select the partition, you want to hide
- click at the gear icon and select *Edit Mount Options*
- disable *Automatic Mount Options*
- make sure *Mount at startup* and *Show in user interface* are unchecked

[image: Disks]

This partition won't be shown after the next login.